# Transfer downloaded google play music from phone to computer?

Tags: usb, google-play-music

I downloaded some music from Google Play on to my phone. Right now I cannot get my (Ubuntu Linux) computer connected to wifi. So my question is if there is any way that I can use a USB/micro USB cable to get the music transferred to my computer?

Answer (score 0):

On **rooted** android, you can find Google Play Music library in

```
/data/data/com.google.android.music/files
```

There is no other way to extract music library from android. You can probably use friend's computer to do that.